# How to create a powershell script which can be reflected to show allowed parameter values

Tags: powershell

I need to reliably read the allowed values for a Cmdlet or PowerShell Script. For example, the allowed values for the `Method` parameter of `Invoke-RestMethod` are `"Get", "Head", "Post",`... etc.

I thus annotate my scripts with `ValidateSet`:

```bsh
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet("GET", "POST")]
    [string]$Method="GET"
)
```

The problem is that I am able to use Get-Help to query these values for Cmdlets like `Invoke-RestMethod` but not for my own scripts.

Here is the output of `$cmd = Get-Help -Full Invoke-RestMethod` looking at `$cmd.syntax.syntaxItem[0].parameter[1].parameterValueGroup.parameterValue`

[image]

```
{
    "name":  "Method",
    "required":  "false",
    "pipelineInput":  "false",
    "isDynamic":  "false",
    "parameterSetName":  "(All)",
    "parameterValue":  {
                           "value":  "WebRequestMethod",
                           "variableLength":  false,
                           "required":  "true"
                       },
    "type":  {
                 "name":  "WebRequestMethod"
             },
    "position":  "Named",
    "aliases":  "None",
    "parameterValueGroup":  {
                                "parameterValue":  [
                                                       "Default",
                                                       "Get",
                                                       "Head",
                                                       "Post",
                                                       "Put",
                                                       "Delete",
                                                       "Trace",
                                                       "Options",
                                                       "Merge",
                                                       "Patch"
                                                   ]
                            }
}
```

The following script allows `"GET"` and `"POST"` as the `Method` parameter but Get-Help does not reflect this.

```bsh
<#
 .Synopsis
 Foo

 .Parameter Method
 Something about method
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet("GET", "POST")]
    [string]$Method="GET"
)
```

Now, if I try to retrieve the "GET" and "POST" allowed values:

```bsh
Set-StrictMode -Off

# 1. Self-reflect
$me = Get-Help .\tmp.ps1 -Full
$me | convertto-json -depth 10  > tmpOP1.json
$methodParamMe = $me.Syntax.syntaxItem[0].parameter | Where-Object Name -eq "Method"
if ($methodParamMe.parameterValueGroup.parameterValue -eq $null) {
    "My ValidateSet is missing!"
} else {
    $methodParam.parameterValueGroup.parameterValue
}

# 2. Look at Invoke-Webreq  
$cmd = Get-Help Invoke-RestMethod -Full
$cmd | convertto-json -depth 10 > tmpOP2.json
$methodParamIWR = $cmd.Syntax.syntaxItem[0].parameter | Where-Object Name -eq "Method"
$methodParamIWR | convertto-json -depth 10 > tmpOP3.json
if ($methodParamIWR.parameterValueGroup.parameterValue -eq $null) {
    "Invoke-RestMethod has no ValidateSet"
} else {
    "Invoke-RestMethod has the set of allowed values!"
    $methodParamIWR.parameterValueGroup.parameterValue | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

**Output:**

```
My ValidateSet is missing!
Invoke-RestMethod has the set of allowed values!
[
    "Default",
    "Get",
    "Head",
    "Post",
    "Put",
    "Delete",
    "Trace",
    "Options",
    "Merge",
    "Patch"
]
```

Is there any way I can annotate my scripts so that I can query the allowed parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information of script itself with `$MyInvocation.MyCommand`.

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Method.Attributes.ValidValues
```

Information on external script files can be obtained as follows.

```
(Get-Command ".\temp.ps1").Parameters.Method.Attributes.ValidValues
```

Comment: I actually need to get this information from *outside* the script. Sorry if this was not clear: I have a process which inspects .ps1 files - this is not about self-reflection.

Comment: Added a way to get information of external script file.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. A pity I have to do Get-Help and Get-Command to get all I need but such is life...

Comment: goodness, so complex. thanks rokumaru.